# Typescript double return type object check

Tags: typescript, object

```
interface TypeOne {
  name: string;
  typeOneProp: any;
}

interface TypeTwo {
  name: string;
  typeTwoProp: any;
}

async function foo(): Promise<TypeOne | TypeTwo> {
   return this.service.get();
}

async function bar(): Promise<any> {
   const data = await foo();
   
   if(data?.typeOneProp) { // errors shown below
      return data.typeOneProp;
   }
}
```

`Property 'typeOneProp' does not exist on type 'TypeOne | TypeTwo'.`

`Property 'typeOneProp' does not exist on type 'TypeTwo'. ts(2339)`

how can i show typescript which return type `foo()` had?

already tried `Object.keys` to see if typeOneProp exists but data remains as `TypeOne | TypeTwo`

`data` intelisense only shows `name` as a property sugestion as is a common property between both types

```
// package.json
"typescript": "^4.4.4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) to check if the property exists on the object ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEDyIUDeAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcJyYWu+AClAHtMtOCHTsAvkSKhIsRCgzZUAdwHJipclVoMmINhy7K1-ISLGTpAEwgIANnCgoYAVxAIwwASGQwBAgAUAJS0ZhTAdBAAPEo8KAA+aNyqAgB87ERwdOgefu6e3r4ARk4hYYIRUdGi6GkaHMgIPgzI1nBgcMgAvMhwKnDAYH4BIeykyI3AMIEA5MbxZpizyKBtHXDBDRMTzmCuUL7tnQB0C3gQS+OkUhJAA)):

```
if('typeOneProp' in data) {
  return data.typeOneProp;
}
```

Comment: for some reason in getting `Property 'typeOneProp' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)` the variable data is `never` inside the if statement, but this can be a solution

Comment: oops, i had a sintax error, that worked

Comment: lol. I'm happy to hear.